# Check folder is open or not

Tags: vb.net

how should i make this go open folder only if only folder it is not open? the folder should only open if it is not open. and put an if, and an else.

```
Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

End Function

    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    'Process.Start(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory)

    folderpath = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Check")
    foldername = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(folderpath)

    If FindWindow(vbNullString, foldername) = 0 Then
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", folderpath)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has a function built in to do this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/ishelldispatch-windows and look at the `windows` property.

When Internet Explorer 4 Desktop Update was released there was no difference between local files and internet files. Therefore it lists Internet Explorer (but no other browser) and Windows Explorer windows.

The `win` in `AllWindows` is actually an Internet Explorer object - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)

```
'ListOpenShellWindows.vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Module MyApplication  

    Sub Main()
            Dim ObjShell as Object
            Dim AllWindows as Object
            objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            AllWindows = objShell.Windows
            For Each win in AllWindows
                Msgbox(win.LocationUrl & " - " & win.LocationName)
            Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

---

To compile copy both files into same folder and double click the batch file.

```
REM ListOpenShellWindows.bat
REM This file compiles ListOpenShellWindows.vb to ListOpenShellWindows.exe using the system VB.NET compiler
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%~dp0\ListOpenShellWindows.exe" "%~dp0\ListOpenShellWindows.vb" 
pause
```

---

**Edit**

If interacting with the *Shell* it is best to use the *Shell* functions. You use `ObjShell.Open` to open a folder. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/ishelldispatch-open.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to not open multiple explorer instances for the same directory, then you can simply pass a new [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) object to the `Process.Start(...)` function. Assign the directory path to the `ProcessStartInfo.FileName` property and the `"open"` command to the `ProcessStartInfo.Verb` property. This way, an already open instance will be activated rather than opening a new one for the same dir.

```vb
' Some caller...
Dim dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Check"))
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo With {
    .FileName = dirInfo.FullName,
    .Verb = "open"
}

Process.Start(psi)
```

On the other hand, if you still need to find out whether a directory is already open in the explorer, then you could *pinvoke* the `FindWindowByCaption` function which returns a handle to a window if any.

```vb
Dim dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Check"))
Dim p = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, dirInfo.Name)

If p = IntPtr.Zero Then
    Process.Start(dirInfo.FullName)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Already Open!")
End If

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindow", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function FindWindowByCaption(zero As IntPtr, lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Of course, the target directory should exist in the first place. Just in case, see the [`DirectoryInfo.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.exists?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Exists);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) property and the [`DirectoryInfo.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.create?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) method.